# symlink from public_html_source to public_html

Tags: linux, git, unix, terminal, symlink

i'm trying to create a symlink between 2 folders on a server that has limited access so I can "deploy" my site.

This is the path to the git repo `/home2/username/public_html_source` and in there there is a folder named `backend_code` Instead of ftp uploading the files of `backend_code` into `/home2/username/public_html`, I would like to make a link to it.

I tried using `ln` but I keep getting a symlink folder inside of `public_html`.

So i'm trying to get
`/home2/username/public_html`

to point to
`/home2/username/public_html_source/backend_code`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remove the /home2/username/public_html folder (after backing it up).

```
rm -R /home2/username/public_html
```

Then apply

```
ln -s /home2/username/public_html_source/backend_code /home2/username/public_html
```

Comment: @Jonathan, the source folder can't be change. when the destination path is present, then the symlink is added inside, when its not, the symlink becomes the correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

### This solution works even if you don't have root privileges of server or using shared hosting...

### Step:1 :: Change your config/filesystems.php

From

```
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

To

```
'links' => [
    base_path('public_html/storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

### Step:2 :: Connect to SSH & Run the following commands

```
$ php artisan optimize
$ php artisan storage:link
$ php artisan optimize
```

it should work now.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken you'd can't link two folders already existing.

What i'd do is save the data in backend_code and then make a symlink.

```
ln -s /home2/username/public_html_source/backend_code /home/username/public_html
```

This should create a symlink called backend_code in side of public_html_source which links to /home/username/public_html

HTH

Comment: i have full access to change/delete public_html folder. the above command made a symlink folder inside public_html called backend_code. Im trying to get that folder to be called public_html and be located one level down. i was almost able to get it with this.`ln -s /home2/username/public_html_source/backend_code /home2/username/` but i need the name of the created symlink folder to be public_html

Comment: OH okay!  Then just change /home/username/public_html_source/backend_code TO /home/username/public_html_source/public_html

Comment: If that worked out for you, i'd really appreciate it if you accepted me as the answer.  :D  If not, lets work it out and get it figured out.